# Embedded PHP in HTML ending early?

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I am currently creating a very basic webpage to test a database.  I am very, very new at web development, so bear with me.  I am attempting to embed php into the html in order to dynamically populate a drop-down menu with a list of universities from a database. However, looking at the source code once I upload it to the server, the embedded php code is being read in-correctly... it is interpreting ">" within a if statement I have to be ending the php, rather than waiting for "?>". How do I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en"> 
 <head> 
  <title>Search</title> 
 </head> 
 <h>Search for your university
 <body> 
    <?php
    //connection to db stuff

    $sql        = "SELECT campus FROM universities";  
    $query      = mysql_query($sql); 
    $options    = "";
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)  //php code cuts off at ">" and simply prints the rest
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            $options .= "<option>" . $row['campus'] . "</option>";
        }
    }
?>
//form stuff
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: It could be a stupid question, but how did you saved the page? As stated by others, your php is not being read by the server, and that '>' is interpreted as html tag and the browser gets confused and prints the rest (but not what comes before). It's either your php install is not configured or your page is a simple html page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try the following code and save it as a .php (for example index.php) file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <title>Search</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Search for your university</h1>

  <?php
  //connection to db stuff

  $sql        = "SELECT campus FROM universities";  
  $query      = mysql_query($sql); 
  $options    = "";
  if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)  //php code cuts off at ">" and simply prints the rest
  {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
        $options .= "<option>" . $row['campus'] . "</option>";
    }
    // Show the dynamicly created options
    echo $options;
  }
  ?>
  //form stuff
  </body> 
</html>
```

I added a fix for your BODY tag. It was added on the wrong place, and a fix for the  tag. That one whas incomplete.

It is not necesary to save a file as .php onto a server to parse it as PHP, but it is recommended and it is easier to understand for other programmers.

Comment: Haha of course... of all the errors, it was something that I knew how to fix, but just missed.  Thanks so much, I think the error was not only was my <h> tag in the wrong place, but I forgot to close it, so it was still looking for a ">" character... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, your file extension is probably `.html` or otherwise.

Rename your file to have a `.php` extension, so the PHP interpreter knows what's going on. Otherwise your web server will serve the page as though all contents are html.

Comment: I renamed it to .php, and now when I view page source the php code is simply non-existant, it doesn't show up at all, and only the html code shows up?  Should it be showing up?

Comment: @jekelija Could be because your code never outputs anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

What it actually sounds like is that your PHP interpreter isn't touching the code at all... If you view-source, you'll see the code.

The `<?php` is being seen as the start of an HTML tag, ending with the `>` in the `if` conditional.

You need to correct your PHP installation so that it works when you have a test .php file like this:

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

This should return a big descriptive page with all the info on your PHP install.  Until you can make that work, you need to start troubleshooting why your PHP install is not working.

Comment: That does work. In fact, I have several other php pages that work perfectly fine, including a log-in page and a register new user page... however those are exclusively php pages with no html, which then redirect to an html page.  So perhaps the server just can't read embedded php code?  Could I find that out from phpinfo?

Answer (score 0):

Such a problem would indicate a hug eproblem with your install of PHP. it should only ever terminate a PHP block when it encounters a `?>`. If `>` would do it, you wouldn't be able to do "greater than" comparisons.

Try removing some things, such as the `if()` portion and leave only the while loop, see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

view source, you'll see all you php code.

the php is not running at all in the server, check your config.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your story I understand you load the page onto a server. So I suspect your PHP handler works well. However to show your PHP output on the page, you need to echo the $options variable. Try the following after the while loop

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)  //php code cuts off at ">" and simply prints the rest
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
        $options .= "<option>" . $row['campus'] . "</option>";
    }
    // Show the dynamicly created options
    echo $options;
}
```

Comment: sorry in the commented out form stuff I have <?php $options> to get it to show up... I should have mentioned that